# Need to get ranked values in a column after group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Card_x  Country Age Code    Card_y  Diff
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    S   9.2
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     S   21.33
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    M   151.4
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     M   202.15
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     G   48.7
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    G   126.82
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    E   19.17
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     E   276.09
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     D   3.05
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    D   69.43
S   INDIA   Adult   Grocery     A   109.47
S   INDIA   Adult   Garments    A   161.75
```

My expected Dataframe:

```
Card_x  Country Age     Code       Card_y
S       INDIA   Adult   Garments    S,E,D,G,M,A
S       INDIA   Adult   Grocery     D,S,G,A,M,E
```

Explanation:
I want to get the Ranked Cards in "Card_y" based on values in "Diff" for each "Code"

For eg.

- 'Garments' has value 'S' with least "Diff" - 9.2 so it comes first.
- 'Garments' has value 'E' with "Diff" - 19.17 so it comes second and so on.

I tried the below code :

```
def get_cards(x):
    extra = {'S', 'A','M', 'E', 'G','D'}.difference(set(x))
    x=x.append(pd.Series(list(extra)))
    return ",".join(x.tolist())

temp1.groupby(['Card_x','Country', 'Age', 'Code'])['Card_y'].apply(lambda x: get_cards(x) ).reset_index()
```

But i didn't get the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.sort_values('Diff').groupby(['Card_x','Country','Age','Code'])['Card_y']\
                      .agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Card_x Country    Age      Code              Card_y
0      S   INDIA  Adult  Garments  [S, E, D, G, M, A]
1      S   INDIA  Adult   Grocery  [D, S, G, A, M, E]
```

Not in list then use

```
df.sort_values('Diff').groupby(['Card_x','Country','Age','Code'])['Card_y']\
                      .agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Card_x Country    Age      Code       Card_y
0      S   INDIA  Adult  Garments  S,E,D,G,M,A
1      S   INDIA  Adult   Grocery  D,S,G,A,M,E
```

Comment: Thanks, but values in Card_y should not be in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `groupby` and `join`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Card_x','Country', 'Age', 'Code', 'Diff'])

df1 = (df.groupby(['Card_x','Country', 'Age', 'Code'])['Card_y']
         .apply(','.join)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Card_x Country    Age      Code       Card_y
0      S   INDIA  Adult  Garments  S,E,D,G,M,A
1      S   INDIA  Adult   Grocery  D,S,G,A,M,E
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, this one also works. But since i used the first code, i had to accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go by first sorting your DataFrame, then GroupBy Card_y and get a list. This should do the trick.

```
df.sort_values("Diff").groupby(["Card_x", "Country","Age","Code"])["Card_y"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Quinteiro,  But since i used the first code, i had to accept it. Thanks again.